# Cannot override 'Protected Overridable Overloads Sub Seed(Context as SchoolContext)' because they have different access levels

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, dbcontext

I am trying to try out this MVC tutorial. The tutorial is in C# but I am trying it using VB.NET, and I'm stuck at this error:

> Public Overrides Sub Seed(Context as SchoolContext)' cannot override 'Protected Overridable Overloads Sub Seed(Context as SchoolContext)' because they have different access levels.

[image: Screenshot]

Can someone help?

Comment: I don't want to be pushy, but I'd like you to accept my answer if it really solved your problem. That way it is removed from the unanswered list, it can be used to mark duplicates in the future, and most importantly it will also indicate to other users that this solved your problem. -- When accepting an answer the answerer will also be given 15 reputation points, and the asker 2 reputation points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is quite clear. You're overloading a function that uses the access level [**`Protected`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8050kawf.aspx), but in your function you use the access level [**`Public`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dc6we3z.aspx).

Change your method declaration to:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Seed(Context as SchoolContext)
    ...your code...
End Sub
```

Comment: @Steve : Glad I could help! Please remember to mark this as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on it. More info about this in the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Steve : Thanks a lot! :)